# How can I serialize Python objects to XML?

Tags: python, serialization, xml-serialization

I need to serialize my Python objects into XML data. I tried to use Django, but it only works for QuerySet objects and not for any simple Python object.

How can I serialize a Python object into XML data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change a Python object into XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334446/how-can-i-change-a-python-object-into-xml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://freshmeat.net/projects/gnosisxml/

Comment: Thanks you very much,
By noticed it serialize Python based objects (list , int ...)
When I give it my custom objects it doesn't serialize it.
Any help
Thanks...

Comment: Hi ,
Thanks , it now works perfectly.
But , I see that the dumps output many attributes I don't really want or don't want to return them to the client to save traffic , like id , module, familly and type.
Do you know a way to drop them.

Thanks...

Comment: This answer should include more details, as [it is currently a link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/351462).

Comment: For any recent readers, gnosis is *long* out of date. I couldn't even install it without messing with its `setup.py`, and then it failed to parse certain things, looking for object properties that no longer exist in the language

Answer (score 3):

You could also have a look at the [objectify](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) module from lxml.

Comment: I haven't actual used the lxml.objectify, but I do prefer lxml for straight xml processing.  Very good library.

Comment: This should include usage examples.