# UnicodeEncodeError when trying to convert Django models to XML

Tags: python, xml, django, encoding, django-models

I found a python program: [Export Django database to xml file](http://siddhi.blogspot.com/2006/09/export-django-database-to-xml-file.html) that converts django models to a xml representation. I get these errors when trying to run the program. My models contain some text written in French.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml_export.py", line 71, in <module>
  writer.content(value)
File "xml_export.py", line 41, in content
  self.output += str(text)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 3:
ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your variable `text` contains a non-ASCII string.

See:

```
>>> mystring = u"élève"
>>> mystring
u'\xe9l\xe8ve'
>>> str(mystring)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So, you first need to encode your string into `UTF-8`:

```
>>> str(mystring.encode("utf-8"))
'\xc3\xa9l\xc3\xa8ve'
```

Or, if (as the comments show) `text` may contain other variable types besides strings, use

```
self.output += unicode(mystring).encode("utf-8")
```

Comment: If I do that I get: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml_export.py", line 71, in <module>
    writer.content(value)
  File "xml_export.py", line 41, in content
    self.output += str(text.encode("utf-8"))
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: That's strange. It means that `text` holds an integer variable. This in turn makes it hard to figure out why there would be an `é` in `text` unless that variable is changing its type along the way (which would be legal in Python) but makes this situation more difficult. You'll need to provide more info - where does `text` come from? What are you doing with it?

Comment: The text data comes from the fields of the database, so the value of a field can contain also numbers.

Comment: I tried unicode(text). This solves the problem in the content method, but then I have another error in the save method at the fp.write(self.output) line. The error I get is this: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml_export.py", line 77, in <module>
    writer.save("export.xml")
  File "xml_export.py", line 48, in save
    fp.write(self.output)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 404
: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 3):

Seriously, don't use the linked code. It's terrible, and appears to have been written by someone with absolutely no knowledge of unicode, character encodings, or even how to build up an XML document. String concatentation? Really?

Just don't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to use the built-in command :

```
./manage.py dumpdata --format xml
```

The way you used unicode in `u'élève'` is ok, so this should work (normalement...).

Comment: I think this command does the same thing as this from django.core import serializers
data = serializers.serialize("xml", SomeModel.objects.all()). I need to have the format from this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757402/convert-python-object-to-xml-representation

Comment: ben alors t'as qu'à utiliser la réponse! si tu déclare bien ton xml avec un encodage utf-8 au début, aucun souci!