# Convert sxw to rml error

Tags: openoffice.org, odoo, rml

When I try to convert sxw file to rml file using OpenOffice , this error occurs :

```
Exception: 'asci' codec can't encode character u'\xe9'
```

what's the meaning of that error? and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

please check this link [UnicodeEncodeError when trying to convert Django models to XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4817018/674598) This is the same issue that we got here.
You can use yourfield.encode("utf-8") or use format() in openerp. [[format(obj.your_str_field or '')]]

Comment: can you tell me where can I use encode("utf-8") because test:fields.text('Test').encode("utf-8") doesn't work

Comment: in openerp addons, you can find a file account > report > account_print_invoice.sxw
In this file you can find a code like [[  format(l.note or '') or removeParentNode('tr') ]]
Here l.note is a text field and it is given in the format() function. try using this format function..

Comment: Thank you sir for your  help.I think some accented char in my .sxw file cause that error

Answer (score 0):

We have Similar issues posted on lp: https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+bug/956798
and it has been fixed on linked branch you can take the patch apply, which will make your report to tolerate the Unicode encoding.

Thank You